# Set an editable variable at Flask app initialization

Tags: python, flask

I want to set a specific variable when the app STARTS. I may need to edit this variable later on. How can I do this?

I know global variables are bad to use because all users will be affected by one user modifying a global. Is it bad practice to edit a configuration value (I remember reading that somewhere)? If so, what's the best way to do this?

My use case is setting the MongoDB collection name. The user may need to change the collection they're using based on the type of analysis they want to perform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's specific to each user, store it in the session. If it's not in the session, use the default.

```
from flask import request, session

@app.route('/change_collection', methods=['POST'])
def change_collection():
    session['collection'] = request.form['name']
    return '', 204

def get_collection():
    name = session.get('collection', 'default')
    return my_data[name]
```